# what is Android VpnService.Builder setBlocking

Tags: android, vpn, android-vpn-service

My question is: what does it really do? For instance, if I set it to true, what does it do to packages (datagrams?) that I want to write to the TUN device? As far as I noticed it does **not** mean that all packets to be written to the TUN device will be discarded rather than processed in another manner. Does it mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/blocking/info)?

So I can only track what it does only this far:

```
public Builder setBlocking(boolean blocking) {
    mConfig.blocking = blocking;
    return this;
}
```

And that

```
public class Builder {
    private final VpnConfig mConfig = new VpnConfig();
    //other stuff here ...
}
```

I also read the [official description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#setBlocking(boolean)), but it is still unclear to me. Googling it will only lead to search results related to "how to bypass VPN blocking".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does refer to blocking I/O and has nothing to do with blocking traffic or how packets are treated. Instead it changes how your program interacts with the file descriptor.

In blocking mode, operations like `read()/write()` will block until some data has been transferred (or an error occurred) whereas in non-blocking mode the operations may return immediately (with `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`) if the file descriptor is currently not ready and the operation would block.